# Where to get android sdk for linux 64bit?

Tags: android, sdk

I searched a lot of websites but nothing found.
Could anyone offer me a url or something like that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 64bit SDK. Just go with the 32bit version to be found [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a 64-bit distribution on your development machine, you need to install the

```
ia32-libs package using apt-get::
apt-get install ia32-libs
Next, install Java:
apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply installing ia32-libs should be enough. In Debian based systems the following command should be good to go:

- apt-get install ia32-libs

The [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) site also mentions the Sun Java package "sun-java6-jdk"  which is no more available. However I am hoping you already have the "Openjdk" equivalent of that which works equally well with no compromises.
Hope it helps.