# 64-bit Android Developer Tools

Tags: android

So ive been trying to get the android development environment up and running and failing miserably to get a simple Hello world program running. So im gonna uninstall everything and start again. I know there are 64 bit versions of the JDK and Eclipse but i was wondering if there is for Android. On the Download page: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html there doesnt seem to be

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to get android sdk for linux 64bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841794/where-to-get-android-sdk-for-linux-64bit)

Answer (score 2):

You should not need any special 64-bit tools. I run 64-bit Ubuntu and develop for Android just fine using the provided SDK/NDK. You are compiling for Android, not your native system. As for the compilers themselves, they run just fine despite being 32-bit inside 64-bit tools/IDEs.

Answer (score 2):

In the last section of http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html Troubleshouoting :
If you are running a 64-bit distribution on your development machine, you need to install the ia32-libs package using apt-get :: 
apt-get install ia32-libs

I guess that while installing android, you missed this point as you had already installed JDK. It turned out that you need ia32-libs for adb (Android Debug Bridge) to run on 32 bit.